# Is it possible to create a live USB stick with a clone of my desktop installation

Tags: live-cd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to customize live Ubuntu CD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-live-ubuntu-cd)

Live USB sticks really come in handy very often. But setting them up (installing and configuring all the programs I need) is tedious, and largely duplicates the effort I make when setting up my ordinary desktop installation.

It'd spare a lot of time if I could just transfer my desktop installation to a bootable USB stick. Is anything like this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [remastersys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remastersys). It allows you to create a LiveCD image from your running system. Once you have a CD image, it can be easily converted to a USBstick-image. Check [Ubuntu Live USB creator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_Live_USB_creator)

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know off at this point is only available for windows.  Its called XBoot.  If you would like to give it a shot [Take a look at this site](http://lifehacker.com/5716173/xboot-creates-your-own-custom-multi+image-bootable-usb-drive)